# Classify new observations in existing clusters

Tags: python, image-processing, conv-neural-network, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am using a dataset comprised of around 19000 images and, with the help of a Convolutional Neural Network (VGG16) and the K-Means function, have sucessfully created 14 clusters of visually similar images.

The issue I'm facing is: I want to classify a **new image** in one of the 14 existing clusters. I have saved both the cluster information and the K-Means labels in Pickle files for easier readability, but am struggling to find a solution that does not involve re-calculating the clusters.

Example of a constructed cluster (cluster ID 14):
[image: Cluster 2]

Is there a way of defining a model with the constructed cluster IDs as targets and, afterwards, classify new images based on that information?

Comment: what are you clustering? the output of the last layer of the network? -- just run the image through the net, and assign it to the nearest cluster *centroid*. you say you still have that.

Comment: Yes, I am running images through a headerless CNN and clustering the 4096-sized feature vectors.

Comment: Is the cluster #14 collecting random images ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, cluster #14 is simply one of 14 clusters containing visually similar images. They are not random, they're limited because my dataset is relatively small.

Comment: Which ones are visually similar ?

Comment: Visually similar keeping mind I have a limited dataset. Out of my total 19000 images, clusters are generated regarding how similar the feature vectors are. So while they might not appear similar, they are the MOST similar.